# (Excel) How do I add an input field to a pivo ttable that is generated from an external source?

Tags: excel, input

I have a pivot table that automatically generates/refreshes from an external data source (atomsvc). I want users to add comments for each row of data and keep this data linked to the external data source (so it moves\deletes when the data gets changed). Is this possible?

Comment: I'm afraid no. By default, all rows inserted by a Pivot Table go the ir own way, so your comments on adyacent cells won't go up/down with the rows of the Pivot Table. Is there any field in the Pivot Table that make each row unique?

Comment: Yes, there are unique values. Any way i can use that?

Comment: If your Pivot Table got always same number of columns and there is a column with unique values to idenfuty each row, you could make a helper Vlookup table in the same page. You could gather data in a different worksheet and call it everytime you update

Answer (score 0):

I made a fake dataset like this (just vendors sales)

[image]

In another worksheet named VLOOKUP got a table where I have comments about each vendor:
[image]

In a third worksheet, got my Pivot Table, where I got each vendor total:

[image]

I can see the coments thanks to a VLOOKUP formula. The formula I'm using is:

`=VLOOKUP(A4;vlookup!$A$4:$B$9;2;FALSE)`

So even if I change the order of Pivot Table, the comments get updated (like sorting Z-A):

[image]

Please, notice that:

1. This will work only if you have any unique field (VENDOR ID in my case)
2. This will work as long as VENDOR ID is always in same column. If it changes, you need to update formula (or make it autoupdatable with MATCH)
3. The adyacent comments will get deleted if you add extra columns.
4. Every time there is a new vendor, you need to add it manually to your VLOOKUP table

Not the best solution, but it may help.